# Existence theorems for first oder semilinear PDE systems with polynomial vector field

Tags: dynamical-systems

The problem is something like:.
$$
B(u(x_1,x_2,...,x_n))+g(x_1,...,x_n,u)=D(u)(A(x)), 
$$
and we have the initial conditions $u(0)=D(u)(0)=0$.

$u=(u_1,...,u_n)$ is the unknown vector field, and it is a vector field from the $n$-dimensional euclidean space to the $n$-dimensional euclidean space; $g$ is a low degree polynomial vector field from the $2n$-dimensional euclidean space to the n-dimensional one, $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ is the vector of variables; $D(u)$ is the derivative of $u$ (the Jacobian matrix); $0$ is the zero vector; $A$ is a  matrix such that all its eigenvalues are positive, while $B$ is matrix such that all its eigenvalues are negative.

The question is: Is it possible to prove that there exists a neighborhood of $0$, say $U$, such that the problem has a single solution $u$ over $U$, and the function $\lVert u\rVert$ is a slow growing function, where $\lVert u\rVert$ is the euclidean norm of $u$?.

Comment: If the answer is positive, can one droop the eigenvalue hypothesis?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I just edited it for you.